# Problem with scrollIntoView not scrolling until the end on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have one component that builds a list of messages for a chat, the `scrollIntoView` function only works when I open the chat for second time, (the first time, it doesn't scroll until the end). I attached some photos and videos and some code.

```
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const { data, isLoading } = useChatMessages(id)
    const { socket } = useSocket()
    const viewRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(['CHATMESSAGES', id], function(oldData) {
                return [...oldData, data]
            })
        })
    }, [socket])

    useEffect(() => {
        viewRef.current && viewRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})
    }, [data])

    if (isLoading) return <span>Loading...</span>


    return (
        <div className={styles.chatMessages}>
            {data.map(message => (
                message.sender_id !== 'x' ? <MessageReceived key={message.id} date={message.date} message={message.message} /> : <MessageSended key={message.id} date={message.date} message={message.message} />
            ))}
            <div ref={viewRef} />
        </div >
    )
}
```

**Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwoKH.gif** (As you can see, I need to scroll manually until the end)
Can someone help me resolving the error?

Comment: try `.scrollIntoView(true);` and remove the options object.

Comment: Ty, its work! Really appreciated.

Comment: Side Notes: You subscribe to the socket, but have nothing for unsubscribing. You should put a return statement, in your `useEffect`, that calls `socket.off('receive_message')`. Also, if your bundler supports optional chaining, you can boil your scroll down to `viewRef?.current?.scrollIntoView?.(true)`. You might need an eslint line disable on 'no-unused-expressions' to use, but effectively only calls method if it exists.

Comment: Ty for the tips, really appreciated!

Comment: Can I suggest that one of you (either @RandyCasburn or @steve-cutter-blades) make the comment an answer to questions for other users?